# Cannot open include file: 'aes.h': No such file or directory (VS 2010)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, wxwidgets

I successfully build boost 1.48 in x86 architecture using visual studio 2010 command:

```
b2 --toolset=msvc-10.0 --build-type=complete stage
```

I got this error when trying to batch build in release mode.

**My VS 2010 project configuration:**

VC++ Directories:

- (Include) D:\boost_1_48_0 (extracted path)
- (Library) D:\boost_1_48_0\stage\lib

C/C++ -> Code Generation:

- (Runtime Library) Multi-threaded(/MT)

Am I missing some configuration?

Additional Info (I dont know if this matters) :I also use wxWidgets

Comment: Are you sure the configuration is the same for both release and debug mode?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore yes..differs only in runtime library code generation.. the rest are the same

Answer (score 1):

Neither boost nor wxWidgets implement any crypto functions ([AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard))

Check whether your app uses [openssl](http://www.openssl.org/) since that is the most likely candidate where you will find such a header.